# JQuery window.parent close effect from iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, parent, innerhtml

The following code loaded in an iFrame should alter the contents of a div on the parent page. It doesn't.

```
var closer = $('#contcomplete').html();
window.parent.jQuery('#contprintframe').html(closer);
```

Any ideas?

EDIT :: This is also not working

```
var closer = $('#contcomplete').html();
$('#contprintframe', window.parent).html(closer);
```

Comment: This? `parent.$('#contprintframe').html(closer);` and are those scripts from the same domain?

Comment: You do have jQuery on both pages?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to 'find' the element you want to change in your parent first, then pass the value.

```
var closer = $('#contcomplete').html();
$('#contprintframe', window.parent.document).contents().find('#div_you_want_to_change').html(closer);
```

Hope it works.